# Angular 2 Structural directive not registering event

Tags: typescript, angular

I am creating a structural directive to add or remove elements in the DOM upon window resize. The problem is that the directive doesn't draw the elements even if the window width is larger than the cut-off value I've set. I tried debugging the directive but I'm not hitting any of my breakpoints inside the event handler for the `window:resize` event.

I put another event handler for `window:resize`using the same method in my component and it would run the handler without any problems (the one in the component).

**my-structural-directive.ts:**

```
import{
    Directive,
    Input,
    TemplateRef,
    ViewContainerRef} from "@angular/core";

@Directive({
    selector: "[visAboveWidth]",
    host : {
        "(window:resize)" : "onResize($event)"
    }
})
export class VisibleAboveWidthDirective{
    private _defaultWidth : number = 786;
    private _visibleAbove : number;

    constructor(private _templateRef: TemplateRef<any>, private  _viewContainer: ViewContainerRef){

    }

    @Input() set visAboveWidth(width: number){
        this._visibleAbove = width;
    }

    onResize(event: Event){
        var window : any = event.target;
        var currentWidth = window.innerWidth;

        if(currentWidth < (this._visibleAbove || this._defaultWidth)){
            this._viewContainer.clear();
        }
        else{
            this._viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this._templateRef);
        }
    }
}
```

**my-html-file.html:**

```
        <!-- Bunch of divs-->
     <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Group</th>
                <th>Type</th>
                <th>Box</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Volume</th>
            <!-- First instance of the directive -->
                <th *visAboveWidth="786"></th>
            <!-- First instance of the directive -->
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let sample of samples">
                <td class="vert-align">{{sample.group}}</td>
                <td class="vert-align">{{sample.type}}</td>
                <td class="vert-align">{{sample.box}}</td>
                <td class="vert-align">{{sample.position}}</td>
                <td class="vert-align">{{sample.volume}}</td>

            <!-- Second instance of the directive -->
                <td class="vert-align" *visAboveWidth="786">
            <!-- Second instance of the directive -->

                    <div class="btn-group" dropdown >
                        <button class="btn btn-default">Details</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-default" dropdownToggle>
                            <span class="caret"></span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Secondary actions</span>
                        </button>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" dropdownMenu>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item">Edit</a></li>
                            <li class="divider dropdown-divider"></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item">Delete</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
```

Neither the elements with the directives attached are shown when the component renders.

At first I thought it was because the structural directive would clear the ViewContainer so I tried this approach instead:

**my-structural-directive.ts**

```
    //Rest is the same 
    constructor(private _elementRef : ElementRef)
    onResize(event: Event){
        var window : any = event.target;
        var currentWidth = window.innerWidth;

        if(currentWidth < (this._visibleAbove || this._defaultWidth)){
            this._elementRef.nativeElement.style.display = "none"
        }
        else{
            this._elementRef.nativeElement.style.display = "block"
        }
    }
```

But this doesn't work either. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

So I managed to solve it. 
I must have misunderstood how structural directives work. When I removed the reference to the ViewContainer and TemplateRef and used the ElementRef it started working. Which I guess makes sense when I think about it.

I changed my directive to the following:
**my-directive.ts**

```
import{
    Directive,
    Input,
    ElementRef,
    HostBinding
    } from "@angular/core";



@Directive({
    selector: "[visAboveWidth]",
    host : {
        "(window:resize)" : "onResize($event)"
    }
})
export class VisibleAboveWidthDirective{
    private _defaultWidth : number = 786;
    private _visibleAbove : number;
    constructor(private _elementRef: ElementRef){

    }

    @Input("visAboveWidth") set visAboveWidth(width: number){
        console.log("Set value");
        this._visibleAbove = width;
    }

    @HostBinding("class.visibility-hide")
    private _hide : boolean = false;

    onResize(event: Event){
        var window : any = event.target;
        var currentWidth = window.innerWidth;

        this._hide = currentWidth < (this._visibleAbove || this._defaultWidth);
    }
}
```

With the new directive syntax being

```
visAboveWidth="786"
```

Instead of the asterix

I also added `.visibility-hide` class to my stylesheet:

```
.visibility-hide{
    display: none;
}
```